# Redux and React - Keeping component props in sync with state via @connect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an application set up using React and Redux such that I have a root application component wrapped around a provider (which is passing the store down so that my child components can access state and dispatch) like so:

```
<Provider store={Store}>
    <RootComponent />
</Provider>
```

My RootComponent essentially uses a JSON file to render Template components that get passed a key and title (

```
<Application children={children} />
```

Within one of the children, I've hooked up the state of the application to the Component using the @connect decorator and I'm firing off a dispatcher upon construction to update my 'content' prop like so:

```
@connect(state => ({content: state.content}))
export default class DynamicText extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var Content = require(`./jsonContent`);
    props.dispatch(loadContent(Content[props.title].elements));
}

**actions.js**
export function loadContent(content) {
    return {
        type: 'LOAD_CONTENT',
        content
    };
}

**reducers.js**
const initialState = {
route: null
};

export default function routeReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOAD_CONTENT:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                content: action.content
            });
        default:
            return state;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that when booting up my application, the 'content' prop is undefined - upon page refresh however, it populates with the updated 'content' data from the JSON file. I think the issue may be occurring because initially the state.content  referenced in my @connect decorator is undefined, however I was hoping that the immediate dispatch on the constructor would solve this issue.

Does anyone have experience or recommendations on how I can get this working without a refresh? Is @connect really the best option here or are there alternatives?

Comment: As far as I understood, you are loading you content synchronically (using `require` function). If so, why can't you just include it in your initial state? On the other hand, if you need to download your data in async way, you can: 1)  make it a part of your state and logic (e. g. add some `loaded` flag to state) 2) call React `render` method only when data loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hydrate your store before passing it down to `Provider` providing an initial state to it so that when your app "boots" your store already has the data available.

Using `connect` is the right way to go after that.
If you're running a server side rendered application you can put your json contents in a property attached to `window` on first request then empty it after store has been hydrated.

Something along the lines of `window.__BOOTSTRAP__`.

```
store = createStore(appReducers, { content: yourJsonFileContents });

<Provider store={store}>
    <RootComponent />
</Provider>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Henrik. I tried passing in the initial state as the second argument to my createStore function and while it did not work, I think it was because I'm using json-loader to parse my JSON file; I'll need to explore why that isn't working. When I hardcoded the content though, it passed down to my child component successfully.


On a side note can you recommend how I can attach the json to window? The initial server request doesn't have access to window.

Comment: What do you mean by server request? You can attach the data in your html using a script tag.